# Store default values and use in comparison in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is not complete atm but demonstrates what i'm trying to do. In my script i have a jQuery function that is storing the default values from all textareas when the pages is first loaded in an array "defaultValues". When the "click function is executed and the idea is to use the array "defaultValues" in the "CheckTextChange" function and check if anny item dosn't match "currentVal". If currentVal has another value a text change has been made and CheckTextChange will return true. I'm wondering, how can i access "defaultValues[]" inside CheckTextChange and how can i use defaultValues[] in the if-statement to check weather anny item dosn't match currentVal?

HTML:

```
<h3>Text1...</h3>
<textarea class="txt">Hejsan</textarea><br/><br />

<h3>Text2...</h3>
<textarea class="txt">Hejdå</textarea><br/><br />

<h3>Text3...</h3>
<textarea class="txt">Hejsan</textarea><br/><br />

<input id="btnClick" type="button" value="Save" />
```

Script:

```
$('#btnClick').on("click", function () {
    if (CheckTextChange()) {
        alert('TRUE');
    } else {
        alert('FALSE');
    }
})

var defaultValues = []; 
    $(document).ready(function(){      
        $('.txt').each(function () {
            var defValue = $(this).get(0).defaultValue;
            defaultValues.push(defValue);
              var v = defaultValues[0];              
        });     
    });


function CheckTextChange() {;
    var isChanged = false;
    $('.txt').each(function () {
        var currentVal = $(this).val();

        //Check if anny item in defaultVaules[] match currentVal
        if (currentVal != previousVal) {
            isChanged = true;
        }
    });

    return isChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the default values as a data attrib...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("data-deftxt", $(this).val());
    });
});

$('#btnClick').on("click", function() {
    if (CheckTextChange()) {
        alert('TRUE');
    } else {
        alert('FALSE');
    }
})

function CheckTextChange() {;
    var isChanged = false;
    $('.txt').each(function() {
        var currentVal = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).val() !== $(this).data("deftxt")) {
            isChanged = true;
        }
    });

    return isChanged;
}
```

Comment: Tried this but the old value in $(document).ready function is returning nothing at all for some reason.

Comment: Dunno why. Works for me. Like to post your updated code?

Answer (score 0):

Use an associative  mapping:

```
var defaultValues = {}; 
$(document).ready(function(){      
    $('.txt').each(function () {
        defaultValues[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();            
    });     
});

    function CheckTextChange() {;
        var isChanged = false;
        $('.txt').each(function () {
            var currentVal = $(this).val();

            //Check if anny item in defaultVaules[] match currentVal
            if (currentVal != defaultValues[$(this).attr('id')]) {
                isChanged = true;
            }
        });

        return isChanged;
    }
```

And set an ID to your fields:

```
<h3>Text1...</h3>
<textarea class="txt" id="field1">Hejsan</textarea><br/><br />

<h3>Text2...</h3>
<textarea class="txt" id="field2">Hejdå</textarea><br/><br />

<h3>Text3...</h3>
<textarea class="txt" id="field3">Hejsan</textarea><br/><br />

<input id="btnClick" type="button" value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to break the loop as follow

```
function CheckTextChange() {;
   var isChanged = false;
   $('.txt').each(function (index) {
      var currentVal = $(this).val();

      //Check if anny item in defaultVaules[] match currentVal
      if (currentVal != defaultVaules[index]) {
         isChanged = true;
         return;
      }
  });

  return isChanged;
}
```